# Control Wifi Signal Strength on a accesspoint

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, wifi, access-point

Is there a mechanism to control the signal strength(Tx power range)/Signal Power in a linux machine(laptop) where the machine acts as a wifi access point.So that In the end i should be able to control the signal range by changing the values.

Comment: That would depend on the particular implementation.  It's certainly possible via the web configuration gui on some custom linux-based firmware for embedded access points.  But there's no guarantee that a given radio/driver exposes this to software.  And even if you have control over transmit power, actual range will depend on other factors such as antennas, sensitivity and transmit power at the client end, interference, obstructions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

with the iw utility installed, try to run:

iw dev wlan0 set txpower fixed *power*

or

iw dev wlan0 set txpower limit *power*

assuming your wlan interface is wlan0, where *power* is a number to specify your output power in units of decibel-milliwatts

Comment: can be done with "sudo iwconfig wlan0 txpower value "